# ReactJS crashes when ran in docker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker

I'm trying to dockerize my react app.

But when I go to run it, it immediately stops. No errors.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
frontend:
    build:
      context: ../frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.react
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"  # Map port 3000 on the host to 3000 in the container
    volumes:
      - ../frontend:/react-app
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3030
    depends_on:
      - apiserver
    networks:
      - mynetwork  # Connect this service to the custom network
networks:
  mynetwork:
```

And here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /react-app

COPY package.json package.json
COPY public/ public
COPY src/ src

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And finally, what shows up in the logs:

```
2023-09-23 02:51:14 
2023-09-23 02:51:14 > frontend@0.1.0 start
2023-09-23 02:51:14 > react-scripts start
2023-09-23 02:51:14
```

When I run it as just an image, without the docker-compose file, it works... where am I going wrong?

I'm at a loss. I've tried everything and have been searching for hours.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Everything. Searched SOF for hours

Comment: May you try running the container interactively and shell into it to see if there's an error?

Comment: The `volumes:` block hides pretty much everything the image build does, including replacing its `node_module` directory with something possibly incompatible; does deleting that block help?

Comment: @DavidMaze your suggestion worked immediately! Thank you!